# Forge Viewer select element by tapping screen not working correctly on Surface Pro using IE 11 (via cordova)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Using Surface pro **touch screen** to select element in viewer works sometimes other times it seems to translate to a rotate/zoom action. In this case the viewer rotates/moves and the element is NOT selected.

When logging the events there are plenty of mouse down/up events along with mouse moves when it doesnt work. When select does work a single click event occurs.

Double click seems to work ok.
Zoom/rotate etc using standard tools works ok.

Using the keyboard cover touch pad that you can get for the Surface pro to move and click works as expected and the element is selected.

Running same application on a GETAC Windows 10 ruggadised tablet the select element works correctly so it seems related to the Surface Pro.

Unable to change browsers as cordova apps use IE11 on windows and that is currently fixed.

The only solution i can think of for the moment is to remove the standard navigation tools completely (somehow) and recreate a select mode tool that would ignore any mouse moves and use button down event to select element.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Tech Details:
Windows 10 Pro,
Surface Pro,
Browser: IE11,
Viewer version 2.11,
Other: WINJS81 cordova application

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

We've had problems with touch events on the Surface Pro in the past.  It sounds like the edges of the touch screen are overly sensitive and are triggering extra touch points.

Does the problem happen if you are holding the device up, gripping with one hand, and using your other hand to touch/select a 3D object ?

Could you try doing a selection again, but this time, make sure you other hand is not holding the edge of the screen?  (Perhaps place the device on the surface of a desk, so you are not holding it up)

Comment: Good idea, i tried using both finger and pointing device with the device on desk and results where still the same. Sometimes it selects other times it does not. It is more likely to do other action (e.g. tiny rotate or tiny move) rather than select an element.

Comment: I just noticed you are using an older version (v2.11) of the viewer.  Can you try [this](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3d.html?svf=https://lmv-models.s3.amazonaws.com/toy_plane/toy_plane.svf) this newer version and tell me if you still experience the same problem?


https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3d.html?svf=https://lmv-models.s3.amazonaws.com/toy_plane/toy_plane.svf

Comment: I haven't setup the latest version of the viewer in my application but I did try the url you supplied on IE11 on the Surface Pro. It still had a similar behaviour. If you show the properties panel and then select an element in most cases (no standard nav tools active) you get a corresponding small rotation and sometimes the element is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix to this issue. In viewer3D in the base toolcontroller there is line

```
var kClickThreshold = 2;
```

This value is used further down in code to determine if singleClick has occured. It does it by comparing XY on down and up events.

```
var deltaX = _downX - event.canvasX;
var deltaY = _downY - event.canvasY;

_downX = -1;
_downY = -1;

if( Math.abs(deltaX) <= kClickThreshold && Math.abs(deltaY) <= kClickThreshold )
    _this.handleSingleClick( event );
```

If movement is above this threshold it does not trigger singleClick if below it does.

Did testing and increasing the value to around 5-7 means that the selection of elements worked consistently. (there is still a minor rotate or zoom at same time as select occurs but I assume that this would be another part of viewer that would need adjusting)

Unfortunately it does require edit of viewer code but easy enough. I added code to overwrite standard value if external variable existed.

Would be nice for future viewer dev if more of these types of properties be exposed so that direct edit of code is not required.

Still it is good to have the source code to be able to debug at this level.

At a guess the Surface Pro 4 must have a more sensitive touch system or it could just be related to IE11 as well.